# how to get field width info of the excel text to column

Tags: excel, vba

While converting text to column using excel wizard. how to get the field info array used in this conversion. for example in the vba code generated in a sample text to column, how can we procure the fieldinfo array used
Array(0, 1), Array(24, 1), Array(44, 1) etc. preferably in a variable

```
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A5"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(24, 1), Array(44, 1), Array(70, 1), Array(79, 1), _
    Array(96, 1), Array(107, 1), Array(118, 1), Array(127, 1), Array(135, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Comment: Procure from where?

Comment: @TimWilliams New to VBA so, please don't mind. But when we go through Text to column wizard in Excel, it automatically calculates these width. However, for my purpose i need to tweak this array as it gets slightly misaligned. For example array(44,1) should ideally be Array(50,1). If we could get these field info that excel detects by default into a variable

Comment: Why not just change it right there in the code?  Do you want to make adjustments at run-time?

Comment: Need to compare the arrays thus arrived between two tables and then basis a criteria select the optimum field width. Array arrived from another table
Array(Array(0, 1), Array(24, 1), Array(50, 1), Array(70, 1)
so need to tweak the third breakpoint as mentioned in question from Array(44,1) to array(50,1). Sort of replicate the manual breakpoint available in the wizard.

Comment: Sounds like you will need to build a similar UI for the user to make those choices - if you don't trust the "automatic" method then you'll always need to have the user make the call?

Comment: The solution that you posted will work, If I know the field info before hand. However, that is not the case. I have two tables, where I need to compare the field width and select the optimum one. The logic i was thinking to solve the issue
1. Find field width of first table
2. Find field width of second table
3. Compare the two
4. Assign filed width from 3 and regenrate the code

Comment: For step 1, where is the first table?  Already imported?  I don't think there's any way to get at the auto-generated `FieldInfo` array at run-time, so I'm not sure what kind of workflow you're planning on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192871/discussion-between-harsh-vardhan-and-tim-williams).

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
Dim fldInfo

fldInfo = Array(Array(0, 1), Array(24, 1), Array(44, 1), Array(70, 1), Array(79, 1), _
                Array(96, 1), Array(107, 1), Array(118, 1), Array(127, 1), Array(135, 1))

Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A5"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                        FieldInfo:=fldInfo, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```